# Concatenate Multidimensional arrays in Julia

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, julia

I have an array of multi-dim arrays `Array{Array{Float64,3},1}` and what I want is a single 4 dimensional array `Array{Float64,4}`.

I have gone through the other responses

- [concatenate array in julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38311405/concatenate-array-in-julia)
- [Concatenating arrays in Julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39586830/concatenating-arrays-in-julia)
- [Multidimensional Array Comprehension in Julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19347799/multidimensional-array-comprehension-in-julia)

But no combination of `cat` and `reshape` seems to do the trick.

There must be a good idiomatic way... what is it?

Answer (score 4):

Your answer is correct and generic. Note, however, that assuming your inner arrays have the same size (not just same dimensionality), there is also the following faster way:

```
julia> matrix = [rand(1,2,3) for _ in 1:4]; # some test data

julia> @btime a = cat($matrix..., dims=4); # your solution
  11.519 μs (80 allocations: 3.83 KiB)

julia> @btime b = reshape(collect(Iterators.flatten($matrix)), (1,2,3,4)); # much faster solution
  611.960 ns (55 allocations: 2.27 KiB)

julia> a == b
true
```

Comment: Any ideas why this happens? Allocations are not that different.

Comment: @GermánBarletta Not really. Would have to check the source code to see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to bother you, I figured it out soon after posting

```
julia> typeof(matrix)
Array{Array{Float64,3},1}

julia> typeof(matrix[1])
Array{Float64,3}

julia> typeof(cat(matrix...,dims=4))
Array{Float64,4}
```